# I'm using angularjs I want to show an element when ng-if condition is false but not on null or undefined

Tags: angularjs

This is the code. I want to display the label when the condition is false but not on null or undefined. But the label is displayed before I click on false.

```
<div>
     <md-radio-group ng-model="data.label">
       <md-radio-button ng-value="true">Yes</md-radio-button>
          <md-radio-button ng-value="false">No</md-radio-button>
       </md-radio-group>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!data.label">
     <label>
      <b>............</b
     </label
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the value of data object? Show us also javascript sources.

Comment: value of the label is defined as null on java object.

Answer (score 0):

Use this condition:

```
<div>
     <md-radio-group ng-model="data.label">
       <md-radio-button ng-value="true">Yes</md-radio-button>
          <md-radio-button ng-value="false">No</md-radio-button>
       </md-radio-group>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="data.label===false">
     <label>
      <b>............</b
     </label
    </div>
```